# Filtering Multiple between_time and ID condition

Tags: pandas, time, between

I know some event happens to those tools at certain timeframe, unfortunately, these events happen at the different timeframe for different tools. I am working on filtering the data to those 2-3 hour time frame to so, I can quantify the improvements and compare before and after the fix. I know we can filter the data based on time using pandas between_time, however, I am not sure how to go about filtering the data by eqp_id and also different time frame. What I am doing is a little crude method, I appreciate if anyone of you has a better and efficient solution for my problem.

```
dmv2361=report1[report1['Eqp_ID'] == 'dmv2361']
df_2361=ALC2361.between_time('01:30', '04:30')

dmv2362=report1[report1['Eqp_ID'] == 'dmv2362']
df_2362=ALC2362.between_time('03:30', '06:30')

dmv2363=report1[report1['Eqp_ID'] == 'dmv2363']
dmv2363=ALC2363.between_time('05:30', '08:30')

I am expecting something like this or better way

alc= report1[report1["Eqp_ID"].isin(['dmv2360', 'dmv2361', 'dmv2362', 'dmv2363', 'dmv2370', 'dmv2371', 'dmv2372', 'dmv2373', 'dmv2374'])].sort_values(by='Start_Date', ascending=True). between_time('23:30-02:30', '01:30-04:30', 'so on')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`indexer_between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html) to do this within a single `loc`:

```
report1[(report1['Eqp_ID'] == 'dmv2361') && report1.index.indexer_between_time('01:30', '04:30')]
```

Note: This is what's called under the hood in `between_time`.

Comment: alc= report1[report1["Eqp_ID"].isin(['dmv2360', 'dmv2361', 'dmv2362', 'dmv2363',
                                                'dmv2370', 'dmv2371', 'dmv2372', 
                                                 'dmv2373', 'dmv2374'])].sort_values(by='Start_Date', ascending=True). between_time('23:30-02:30', '01:30-04:30', 'so on')       This is what I am expecting. I am not sure if its possible